# Check for duplication inside a plist

Tags: macos, plist

I'm making a word game, and storing the words in a plist that I'm editing manually.

It now contains more than 600 words. When I write in new ones I'm always concerned, that the words already exist. I always have to search before I type a new one in, and this is really slows down the whole process.

Is there any way that I can check the list for duplication when I type in immediately, or check the whole plist for duplication and delete the duplicated words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make yourself a helper tool.

The tool will read in the array of strings from the plist and convert it to a set. Then it will accept new strings as input, adding them to the set. Duplicates simply won't be added. Convert the set back to an array before writing the file out.

Comment: Thanks, so set isn't accept duplications? And i have another question how can i write to plist? I reader a lot of tutorial about it but i still fail always i try it.